# SqlAlchemy - When should new session creation occur?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Being new to SQLAlchemy, I was wondering at what time would      `Session()` should be called, in say, a view.  Should it be defined as a global variable, or should a new session be created for each request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I strongly recommend you follow the [Pyramid SQLAlchemy tutorial](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/lastest/tutorials/wiki2/index.html). It teaches you how to use SQLAlchemy with Pyramid in a simple Wiki application.

You'll note that tutorial a `models.py` module is created which defines a `DBSession` item. This gives you access to the SQLAlchemy session, scoped to a Pyramid thread and tied to the Pyramid transaction model, and which is imported whenever you need the session:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config

from .models import (
    DBSession,
    MyModel,
    )

@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemplate.pt')
def my_view(request):
    one = DBSession.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.name=='one').first()
    return {'one':one, 'project':'tutorial'}
```

In `models.py` the DBSession variable is defined as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    scoped_session,
    sessionmaker,
    )

from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
```

Note the `ZopeTransactionExtension`; Pyramid automatically starts a new transaction with each request, committing it on successful responses, aborting it when an exception occurs. This relieves you of most transaction handling duties. Just remember to `.flush` your session when you need to see updates to the database (such as auto-incrementing primary keys).

Again, the tutorial expands on all this and more.

Comment: I just wanted to add a tiny note that this only works with `pyramid_tm` activated or another transaction manager that is aware of the `transaction` package. :-)

Comment: @MichaelMerickel: Indeed; the tutorial makes sure it is activated. The tutorial is so much more comprehensive than a mere SO answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after reading some more of the sqlalchemy docs, I found the correct answer to my question, where a new contextual session should be created with each request.  See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#lifespan-of-a-contextual-session

Comment: And how is this different from my answer, then?

Comment: In your answer, your code states that the DBSession should be used directly, which in the docs, it states that a contextual session should be created for each request. So:

    @view_config()
    def get_view(request):
        session = DBSession() and therefore creating a new session for each request.

Comment: Read the tutorial I linked to, see https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/docs/tutorials/wiki2/src/basiclayout/tutorial/views.py

Comment: Hrm, there is a hosting hickup for the pylons project ATM, wait a little while.

Comment: Wiz, Martin's answer is correct in the context of Pyramid where other packages (pyramid_tm, zope.sqlalchemy and transaction) control the lifecycle for you. The only setup required to make a session per-request is to make a scoped session that uses the ZopeTransactionExtension.

Comment: Oh, he never mentioned that the packages control the life cycle for you. But he doesn't create sessions per-request even though he is using ZopeTransactionExtension.